# Shower with very low ceiling, okay?

Tags: bathroom, walls, shower, ceiling

This shower under construction has a low ceiling of around 6.6 feet. Not an accurate measurement, but I'm like 5.7 feet and I can stand fine and can touch the ceiling with my arms slightly bent.  Will it be damaged by moisture since it's hanging low? Should I tear it down to stay on the safe side?  You can just barely fit a high shower head without it hitting the ceiling.

[image]

The bricks are new walls to make a room out of open space, no drywalls.

Comment: I have lived in county's that had required heights for shower heads that I thought were ridiculously low as I am 6'5" so this may be worth looking into. Backer board would be helpful in making a nice shower surround but the walls can be skim coated, I find that some skim coats last if the walls are dry but if in a area that the walls sweat skim coats tend to flake. With a window no fan is usually required if the opening is a minimum of 2 square feet total if memory serves.

Comment: The walls are interior in a desert climate in Egypt. I didn't make the walls, they supposed to be cement and flat in the end. Is that same as skim coated? What worries me are bricks are neat like an exposed brick wall you find in living rooms, it's messy and uneven. Then sheets for moisture before tiling. The window is huge, like 1.5 meters wide.

Answer (score 1):

The Code requires a height of 6’-4” from the standing surface of the shower to the ceiling of the shower. (See ICC R305.1, exception #1.) Also, the shower shall be a minimum of 24” x 30” and have a non-previous surface up 6’ from shower floor surface.

Minimum room heights are 7’-0”, unless the ceiling slopes, then it’s complicated, except bathrooms shall have a minimum ceiling height of 6’-8”, unless it slopes. (See ICC R305.1.)

Answer (score 0):

"Yikes"

To answer your core question, the height of a shower doesn't have a specific regulation that I'm aware, you choose where you want it. However.....

The idea that too low or too high might cause damage to the ceiling is 100% accurate, in the sense that water reflecting off of you or other items and directly bouncing onto the ceiling will accelerate "damage" - so.....

What to do?

First, a question: Are you really NOT going to put up cement board? It's made for this environment. Also, water getting onto mortar is going to cause efflorescence. So, you MUST cover the walls with something... and ideally, it should be water tight/caulked.

So with my note above, why not just [buy a shower surround that includes a vinyl ceiling](https://www.faucet.com/kohler-k-1687-sonata-48-one-piece-shower-module-with-integral-high-dome-ceiling-less-grab-bar-kit/f161665?source=gg-gba-pla_161665!c203626368!a14806870248!dc!ng&cvosrc=pla.google.161665&cvo_cid=203626368&cvo_crid56686742928=&=&cvo_adgroup=14806870248&cvo_uniqueid=161665&gclid=Cj0KCQjwg7HPBRDUARIsAMeR_0izSoYOuDRpEUAr5oxov2V7_ot1lvlfQ36UaD0XwXzOIDXW2Z_S0fMaAgyVEALw_wcB) (do a google search for numerous options)...

Further, regardless of the space, it is STRONGLY advisable (and in most places required by code) to install a ceiling fan in lieu of other proper vent options. [It needs to be correctly sized for the room it is in](http://www.nutone.com/docs/catalogs/bath-ventilation-fans-heating-products.pdf), to evacuate the moisture. So if the room is "one big room, you will need a large fan for it, and locate it NEAR the source of moisture. This is really a MUST HAVE and will aid in reducing damage to the belongings in the room.

Comment: yes i think that will turn into wall with tiles, no cement board though. Over here most homes are just mortar and cement. The walls i think arnt framed in any way so i dont know if thats right. I have window, and i may install a fan in it, but it will look ugly. Again, cant be ceiling fan, there is no structure to support it, its not a dropped ceiling with vents, and it will be costly.

Comment: You might want to revise your question, and tell us where you are. Looking at the way the drain pan is installed currently does not look like enough to put up a studded wall. The cement board is common and used... almost everywhere. It is like drywall, but "cement" and somewhat flexible. It would give you a good backing for tile. (perfect for what it is meant to do). Get the moisture out of the air is key. The brick is a mess, so pop a side hole in and drop a fan in there if its an outside wall. It looks like the brick needs to be repointed all over

Comment: Repointed? I didn't do the walls so I don't know. It's not an outside all, all interior. It does look bad but I guess for the purpose they didn't care to make it neat. They bricks would be covered, and they will put up something like anti moisture sheets before the tiles. I imagine the cement they use will flatten it. This is in egypt, never seen cement boards here ever. For the shower drain, I don't know why they installed it now, especially since wall is not done but they said they can't remove it.